# How to create this double condition?

Tags: php

I want `$bar` to be "1" if both:
The url has ANY parameter value,
unless it has a foo parameter that is equal to `a`:

tried this and got a syntax error:

```
if ( (!empty($_GET)) && (isset($_GET['foo']!=="a")) )
{
$bar = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Completing your way of doing it you would need something like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET) && (!isset($_GET['foo']) || $_GET['foo'] !== 'a'))
```

This code says: `if get is not empty and (either foo is not set or foo is not equal to a).`

However, chances are that you still need `$bar` to be set to a value regardless of `$_GET` so for clarity and ease of code, I would suggest setting a default value to `$bar` and changing it's value if `$_GET['foo']` is equal to "a" or `$_GET` is not empty. This will make everything easier to understand. Something like:

```
//set a default value
$bar = 0;
//if the url has any parameter
if(!empty($_GET)){
    //set bar to 1
    $bar = 1;
    //unless the url has foo and foo is equal to 'a'
    if(isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo'] == 'a'){
        //set it to a different value
        $bar = 2;
    }
}

//now using $bar down here won't throw a notice error for not being
//defined and will be set to the correct value, with easy enough logic
//for anyone to follow.
```

Comment: ok, I think that's better, yet in your condition as long as foo equals anything it will work, rather than a. maybe there are brackets missing?

Comment: That's what you said in your description. "If the url has any parameter unless it has foo and foo is equal to `a`". This does exactly that. If `$_GET['foo']` is equal to `a`, `$bar` will not be set. All other conditions it will. I added comments to the second bit of code to follow along with what you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
isset($_GET['foo'])
```

always returns boolean value. So consider this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the isset, first validate if GET['foo'] is define then if the value is diferent from "a"

```
if ( (!empty($_GET)) && isset($_GET['foo']) && ($_GET['foo'] !=="a") )
{
    $bar = "1";
}
```